# Highmap Bubble exclude points not on map

Tags: highcharts

Have a dataset of global data with lat/lon info and can display a map of type 'mapbubble.'

Say, however, I only want to display one country. Currently if I use this dataset and display with say, Canada or China, the image of the country shrinks so as to allow all the points -- from all over the world -- to display.

Is there a way to tell Highmap to not display data that is not within the bounds of the current map?

Thanks!

Update: adding sample code. Note that the 4th point is the north pole and not part of China, yet it is displayed (oddly, far to the left and with the bubble not AFAIK the right size).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/offline-exporting.js"> 
</script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"> 
</script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/cn/cn-all.js"> 
</script>

 <style>
     #container {
        height: 500px;
        min-width: 310px;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
     .loading {
       margin-top: 10em;
       text-align: center;
       color: gray;
 }</style>

 <div id="container"></div>
 </head>

 <body>
 <script>
 var H = Highcharts,
        map = H.maps['countries/cn/cn-all'],
       chart;
 var data =  [
    {
        lat:39,
        lon:80,
        z:500
    },
    [{
        lat:31,
        lon:117,
        z:500
    }],
    {
        lat:39,
        lon:82,
        z:600
    },
    {
        lat:0,
        lon:0,
        z:500
    }

];

chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps lat/lon demo'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Basemap',
        mapData: map,
        borderColor: '#606060',
        nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
        showInLegend: false
    },
    {
        name: "test",
        type:"mapbubble",
        minSize: 20,
        maxSize: '30%',
        data: data,
        color: 'rgba(200,0,0,0.5)'
    }]

});
console.log(chart);




</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Barry Briggs, Could you provide me with some live example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @ppotaczek sample code added. note the fourth point. Ideally there would be a way to tell the code to exclude points not within the lat/lon boundaries of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` properties for axes:

```
xAxis: {
  min: -999,
  max: 9851
},

yAxis: {
  min: -9851,
  max: -927
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4876/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/xAxis.min

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/yAxis.max

Comment: Thanks! What are the meanings of the min/max values?

Comment: Hi @Barry Briggs, These are axis units. You can the default values in the chart object.

Comment: Thanks again! Solved my problem.